# scala generic type inference to nothing

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have the following code using ReaderWriterState from Scalaz. My generic type parameter K is inferred as Nothing during compilation. Can someone please tell me what is going on?

```
object O {
    type VM = VirtualMachine

    def getQueue[K, R]: RWS[VM, Map[K, R], EventQueue, Unit] = RWS {
        case (vm, s) => (Map[K,R](), (), s)
    }

    def processEventSet[K, R](f: Event => R): RWS[VM, Map[K,R], EventQueue, Seq[R]] = RWS {
        case (vm, q) => 
            val set = q.remove
            (Map.empty[K, R], set.eventIterator.toSeq map f, q)
    }

    def resume[K, R]: RWS[VM, Map[K,R], EventQueue, Seq[R]] = RWS {
        case (vm, q) => vm.resume();(Map.empty[K,R], List.empty[R], q)
    }

    def process(f: Event => Int): RWS[VM, Map[Int, Int], EventQueue, Seq[Int]] = for {
        _ <- getQueue
        res <- processEventSet(f)
        _ <- resume
    } yield res

    def processT[K, R](f: Event => R): RWS[VM, Map[K,R], EventQueue, Seq[R]] = for {
        _ <- getQueue
        res <- processEventSet(f)
        _ <- resume
    } yield res
}
```

The error(sbt 11.3, scalaz 7.3) on the line of

*res <- processEventSet(f)*
of *processT*

```
**found   : Seq[R] => scalaz.IndexedReaderWriterStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,O.VM,Map[Nothing,R],com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,Seq[R]]
[error]     (which expands to)  Seq[R] => scalaz.IndexedReaderWriterStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine,Map[Nothing,R],com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,Seq[R]]
[error]  required: Seq[R] => scalaz.IndexedReaderWriterStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,O.VM,Map[K,R],com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,Seq[R]]
[error]     (which expands to)  Seq[R] => scalaz.IndexedReaderWriterStateT[scalaz.Id.Id,com.sun.jdi.VirtualMachine,Map[K,R],com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,com.sun.jdi.event.EventQueue,Seq[R]]
[error]                 res <- processEventSet(f)
[error]                     ^
[error] XXX:218: diverging implicit expansion for type scalaz.Semigroup[Map[K,R]]
[error] starting with value intInstance in trait AnyValInstances
[error]                 _ <- getQueue
[error]                   ^**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

```
def processEventSet[K, R](f: Event => R): RWS[VM, Map[K,R], EventQueue, Seq[R]]
```

doesn't have any clue on how to infer the type `K`. All types should be inferable from the function arguments.

You may want to either provide it explicitly, or create another argument (even implicit) that will allow the compiler to infer the type. For example:

```
trait TypeHelper[K,R]
implicit object intHelper extends TypeHelper[Int, Int] 

def processEventSet[K, R](f: Event => R)(implicit ev: TypeHelper[K,R]): 
  RWS[VM, Map[K,R], EventQueue, Seq[R]]
```

This might give the compiler enough information to infer the type. (Though I haven't tested it.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it and it does not solve the problem. According to your answer, I can imagine if f is f:K => R, should it satisfy the compiler? (Does not apply in my case though.)

Comment: For the compiler to be able to infer types, it needs some clue. If the type appears in arguments, the compiler knows the type of argument and can infer unknown type parameters. Then they are used to calculate resulting type. `K` in your case is not present in arguments. So compiler cannot infer it. How can compiler guess what `K` should be equal to?